# Better way compare nodes in a list

Tags: python, list, nodes

Noob, trying to add 'unique' Nodes to a list, i.e. with my simple code, I only want the 2 unique nodes, not any duplicate entries. I found a poor workaround, where I created a temp list, added the values (as list items, not as nodes) to the temp list if unique, and then added all items from temp to my list of Nodes (converting them to Nodes at that point), but I'm sure there's a better much cleaner way to do this.

```
class Node():
    # current actor, source, movie
    def __init__(self, state, parent, action):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action = action

x = Node(5,4,3)
y = Node(5,4,2)
z = Node(5,4,3)

listz = []

if x not in listz:
    listz.append(x)

if y not in listz:
    listz.append(y)

if z not in listz:
    listz.append(z)

for item in listz:
    print(item.state, item.parent, item.action)

Current Outputs (incorrect):
5 4 3
5 4 2 
5 4 3

Should Output (correct):
5 4 3
5 4 2
```

Simple solutions I can follow and implement are preferred to clever ones I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can declare a **eq**() method in your `Node` class to easily compare nodes with each in a way you want.

What this does is that everytime you insert a node and call the `Not in` method, it calls this `__eq__` method instead of the default way to compare nodes, and hence is able to detect similar Nodes. What was happening to your original code was that the `Not in` was just comparing the memory location of all nodes (which are always different)

For example,

```
class Node():
    # current actor, source, movie
    def __init__(self, state, parent, action):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action = action
    def __eq__(self, b):
        return (self.state == b.state) and (self.parent == b.parent) and (self.action == b.action)

x = Node(5,4,3)
y = Node(5,4,2)
z = Node(5,4,3)

listz = []

if x not in listz:
    listz.append(x)

if y not in listz:
    listz.append(y)

if z not in listz:
    listz.append(z)

for item in listz:
    print(item.state, item.parent, item.action)
```

Comment: Do I need to chance something else, my code still outputs the same: https://repl.it/repls/GregariousNonstopData

Comment: the `__eq__()` method must be within the Node class, as it provides operations on the Node object. I've made the relevant change to the code on the link, please have a look now

Comment: Note that each membership lookup in a list requires *O(n)* in time complexity, so if efficiency is a concern you should consider a hash-based implementation, which will allow membership looks to be done in constant time.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is an ordered set, which Python does not natively support, but which you can emulate with keys of a dict, which is guaranteed to maintain insertion order since Python 3.7 (or you can use `collections.OrderedDict` for prior versions).

To make two `Node` objects with the same attribute values recognized as identical as keys of a dict, however, you should define both the `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods with the hash from a tuple of the relevant attributes:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, state, parent, action):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action = action
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.state, self.parent, self.action))
        # you can also use the following instead if don't want to hard-code attributes:
        # return hash(tuple(vars(self).values()))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return hash(self) == hash(other)
```

so that:

```
x = Node(5,4,3)
y = Node(5,4,2)
z = Node(5,4,3)

listz = {}
for item in x, y, z:
    listz[item] = None

for item in listz:
    print(item.state, item.parent, item.action)
```

outputs:

```
5 4 3
5 4 2
```